# Test Queueable Apex: Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped

Tags: apex, unit-test

Hi I'm testing a queueable apex class with callouts in it.
But I got error and have no idea how to fix it.

Callout Class:

```
global class CE_GetSessions implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts{
//key:sessionkeys
private Map<String,CE_Training_Session__c> MapSessions;

public void execute(QueueableContext context){     
    HttpResponse response = this.getSessionKeys();
    if(response!=null){
    this.processSessionKeys(response);
    insert(MapSessions.values());}
}

public CE_GetSessions() {
    MapSessions = new Map<String,CE_Training_Session__c>();       
}



//get the sessionkeys of live sessions that starts with "CE Sales"
//creates CE_Training_Session__c records
//Insert the session information as CE_Training_Session__c(Record_ID__c,Conf_Name__c,Duration__c,Session_Key__c,Start_Time__c,Time_Zone__c )
HttpResponse  getSessionKeys()
{
    System.debug('Entered getSessionKeys');    
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml' );
    req.setBody(CE_Utilities.getLsttrainingsessionHistoryXML(CE_Utilities.quarterStartString,CE_Utilities.quarterEndString));
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    if(res.getStatusCode()==200){
        return res;
    }
    else{
        System.debug('getSessionKeys failed');
        return null;
    }
}


void processSessionKeys(HttpResponse  response)
{
    dom.Document resDoc = response.getBodyDocument();
    dom.XmlNode root = resDoc.getRootElement();
    dom.XmlNode bodyElement = root.getChildElement('body', CE_Utilities.webexEndpoint);
    dom.XmlNode bodyContent = bodyElement.getChildElement('bodyContent',CE_Utilities.webexEndpoint);
    List<dom.XmlNode> historys = bodyContent.getChildElements();
    For(dom.XmlNode history : historys)
    {               
        dom.XmlNode confNameNode = history.getChildElement('confName', CE_Utilities.historyEndpoint);
        if(confNameNode!=null){
        String confName=confNameNode.getText();                    
        if(confName!=null&&confName.length()>=8&&confName.substring(0,8)=='CE Sales')
        {
            CE_Training_Session__c cts=new CE_Training_Session__c(Conf_Name__c=confName);               
            cts.Session_Key__c=history.getChildElement('sessionKey', CE_Utilities.historyEndpoint).getText();
            String startTime = history.getChildElement('sessionStartTime', CE_Utilities.historyEndpoint).getText();
            String stringDate = startTime.substring(6,10) + '-' + 
            startTime.substring(0,2) + '-' +
            startTime.substring(3,5) + ' ' +                    
            startTime.substring(11,19);
            System.debug('stringDate: '+stringDate);
            cts.Start_Time__c=Datetime.valueOf(stringDate);
            String duration = history.getChildElement('duration', CE_Utilities.historyEndpoint).getText();
            cts.Duration__c = integer.valueof(duration);
            cts.Time_Zone__c = history.getChildElement('timeZoneWithDST', CE_Utilities.historyEndpoint).getText();
            if(!MapSessions.containsKey(cts.Session_Key__c))
            {
                MapSessions.put(cts.Session_Key__c,cts);
            }

        }   }                 
    }
    System.debug(MapSessions);
}
```

}

Mock Class:

```
@isTest
global class CE_HttpCalloutMockgetSessionKeysresponse implements HttpCalloutMock{
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    System.debug('CE_HttpCalloutMockgetSessionKeysresponse');
    System.assertEquals(endpoint, req.getEndpoint());
    System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml' );
    res.setBody(CE_Utilities.getLsttrainingsessionHistoryXMLRESPONSE());
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
}
}
```

Test Method:

```
@isTest static void test_CE_GetSessions () {
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new CE_HttpCalloutMockgetSessionKeysresponse());
    Test.startTest();               
    CE_GetSessions cls= new CE_GetSessions();
    System.enqueueJob(cls);
    Test.stopTest();
    List<CE_Training_Session__c> trainingSessions = [select Conf_Name__c,Duration__c,Session_Key__c,Start_Time__c,Time_Zone__c from CE_Training_Session__c];
    System.assertEquals(4,trainingSessions.size());
}
```

It seems like the respond method in the mock class is not entered.

**UPDATE:**

**@Adrian Larson, how is this a duplicate? and why did you remove your comment**

WebServiceMock interface is used for WebServiceCallout.invoke(). Here I'm using Httprequest. When testing these methods, you can instruct the Apex runtime to generate a fake response whenever WebServiceCallout.invoke is called. To do so, implement the WebServiceMock interface and specify a fake response that the Apex runtime should send.

Comment: you need to call the setMock method after the Test.StartTest()

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe it gave me the same result. I checked the debug log and didn't see the printed message from the Mock class. So I think the in the execute method "HttpResponse response = this.getSessionKeys();" is not firing the respond method.   By the way, I someone also calls setMock before Test.StartTest() : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66947/callout-loop-not-allowed-in-unit-test-for-queueable-that-implements-httpcallou

Comment: remove the @isTest from the MockImplementation class? Probably will not help but worth a shot. Otherwise it may be a bug in the queue able interface

Comment: @Eric still the same though.

Comment: Maybe try putting the setMock in the actual class where the callout is made, perhaps just right before? something like Http http = new Http(); if(Test.isRunningTest) Test.sockMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new CE_HttpCalloutMockgetSessionKeysresponse()); HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

Comment: @AdrianLarson WebServiceMock interface is used for WebServiceCallout.invoke(). Here I'm using Httprequest.  When testing these methods, you can instruct the Apex runtime to generate a fake response whenever WebServiceCallout.invoke is called. To do so, implement the WebServiceMock interface and specify a fake response that the Apex runtime should send.